# Using Python to separate into mRNA readable regions to obtain separated proteins

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a program to do the following:

- The input could be a DNA sequence (antisense or sense) or an mRNA sequence.
- Through the DNA sequence, obtain a complementary mRNA sequence.

The program would look for, and print, the readable regions of the mRNA sequence and translate these regions into amino acid sequences.

The problem is that I forgot to separate the readable regions and therefore the readable regions are all together and so are the AA sequences.
What is the best way to separate them and present the results?

```
#DNA->RNA->Protein

print ('Are you using a DNA ou RNA string?')
RNAS= 'RNA'
Resp=input().upper()
if "DNA" in Resp: #convert DNA to RNA
    print('Is the strand sense or antisense? Meaning, from 5 to 3 or from 3 to 5?')
    Resp2= input().upper()
    if "ANTISENSE" in Resp2: #reverse
        print ('Please input the string')
        DNAs=input().upper()
        RNAs = DNAs.replace('A', 'u').replace('T', 'a').replace('C', 'g').replace('G', 'c').upper()[::-1]
        print ('The complementar RNA strand is:')
        print (RNAs)
    else:
        print ('Please input the string')
        DNAs=input().upper()
        RNAs = DNAs.replace('A', 'u').replace('T', 'a').replace('C', 'g').replace('G', 'c').upper()
        print ('The complementar RNA strand is:')
        print (RNAs)
if "RNA" in Resp:
    print ('Please input the string')
    RNAs=input().upper()

# search for readable regions
def readable(seq, n):
    for i in range(0, len(seq), n):
        yield seq[i:i+n]

def method(seq, start=['AUG'], stop=['UAA','UAG','UGA']):
    response = ''
    started = False
    for x in readable(seq, 3):
        if x in start:
            started = True
        if x in stop:
             started=False
        if started:
            response += x
                
    yield response

for result in method(RNAs):
    b=result
print (' ')
print ('The readable part of the RNA is:')
print(result)

def translate(seq): #translate the readable region
      
    table = {
        'AUA':'I', 'AUC':'I', 'AUU':'I', 'AUG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACU':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAU':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGU':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                 
        'CUA':'L', 'CUC':'L', 'CUG':'L', 'CUU':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCU':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAU':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGU':'R',
        'GUA':'V', 'GUC':'V', 'GUG':'V', 'GUU':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCU':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAU':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGU':'G',
        'UCA':'S', 'UCC':'S', 'UCG':'S', 'UCU':'S',
        'UUC':'F', 'UUU':'F', 'UUA':'L', 'UUG':'L',
        'UAC':'Y', 'UAU':'Y', 'UGG':'W', 'UGU':'C',
        'UGC':'C'}
    protein =""
    if len(b)%3 == 0:
  
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
            codon = seq[i:i + 3]
            protein+= table[codon]
    return protein
p = translate(b)
print (' ')
print ('The aa sequence is:')
print (p)
print('')
print('')
print ('Ready to close programm? Yes or no')

Close=input().lower
if "yes" in Close:
    print('Bye')
```

Edit:

```
def method(seq, start=['AUG'], stop=['UAA','UAG','UGA']):
    response = ''
    started = False
    for x in readable(seq, 3):
        if x in start:
            started = True
            response += ' '
        if x in stop:
            started=False
        if started:
            response += x
                
    yield response

for result in method(RNAs):
    b=result
print (' ')
print ('The readable part of the RNA is:')
print(result)
print (' ')
print ('Considering a minimum of 30 nucleotides, the readable part of the RNA is:')
f=result.split()
readable_regions=[x for x in f if len(x)>=int(30)] #readable regions
```

Comment: 1) `RNAs = DNAs.replace('A', 'u').replace('T', 'a').replace('C', 'g').replace('G', 'c').upper()` why replace upper case letters by lower case letters only to reconvert them into uppercase letters? 2) Why not use the `translate` string method for this rather than take 4 separate passes over the data? 3) Breaking DNA up into coding regions is a very deep problem in bioinformatics. No simple arithmetical solution is possible (unless this is a toy program). How are you defining "readable regions"?

Comment: I defined readable regions as starting with the AUG codon, ending in a stop codon ('UAA','UAG','UGA'), and a minimum of 30 nucleotides but I see how it can be problematic. This is still an exercise program.

Answer (score 0):

Only fixed the initial problem, no optimization change yet.

```
print ('Are you using a DNA ou RNA string?')
RNAS= 'RNA'
Resp=input().upper()
if "DNA" in Resp: #convert DNA to RNA
    print('Is the strand sense or antisense? Meaning, from 5 to 3 or from 3 to 5?')
    Resp2= input().upper()
    if "ANTISENSE" in Resp2: #reverse
        print ('Please input the string')
        DNAs=input().upper()
        RNAs = DNAs.replace('A', 'u').replace('T', 'a').replace('C', 'g').replace('G', 'c').upper()[::-1]
        print (' ')
        print ('The complementar RNA strand is:')
        print (RNAs)
    else:
        print ('Please input the string')
        DNAs=input().upper()
        RNAs = DNAs.replace('A', 'u').replace('T', 'a').replace('C', 'g').replace('G', 'c').upper()
        print (' ')
        print ('The complementar RNA strand is:')
        print (RNAs)
if "RNA" in Resp:
    print ('Please input the string')
    RNAs=input().upper()

# search for readable regions
def readable(seq, n):
    for i in range(0, len(seq), n):
        yield seq[i:i+n]

def method(seq, start=['AUG'], stop=['UAA','UAG','UGA']):
    response = ''
    started = False
    for x in readable(seq, 3):
        if x in start:
            started = True
            response += '   '
        if x in stop:
            started=False
        if started:
            response += x
                
    yield response

for result in method(RNAs):
    b=result
print (' ')
print ('The readable part of the RNA is:')
print(result)
print (' ')
print ('Considering a minimum of 30 nucleotides, the readable part of the RNA is:')
f=result.split()
readable_regionslist=[x for x in f if len(x)>=int(30)] #readable regions
separator = '   '
readable_regions=(separator.join(readable_regionslist))
print(readable_regions)


def translate(seq): #translate the readable regions
    table = {
        'AUA':'I', 'AUC':'I', 'AUU':'I', 'AUG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACU':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAU':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGU':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                 
        'CUA':'L', 'CUC':'L', 'CUG':'L', 'CUU':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCU':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAU':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGU':'R',
        'GUA':'V', 'GUC':'V', 'GUG':'V', 'GUU':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCU':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAU':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGU':'G',
        'UCA':'S', 'UCC':'S', 'UCG':'S', 'UCU':'S',
        'UUC':'F', 'UUU':'F', 'UUA':'L', 'UUG':'L',
        'UAC':'Y', 'UAU':'Y', 'UGG':'W', 'UGU':'C',
        'UGC':'C', '   ':'   '}
    protein =""
    if len(b)%3 == 0:
  
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
            codon = seq[i:i + 3]
            protein+= table[codon]
    return protein
p = translate(b)


p = translate(readable_regions)
print (' ')
print ('The aa sequence is:')
print (p)
```